# Error when changing navigation status bar text color in objective-c

Tags: ios, colors, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the text color in the status bar and everything within the navigation.

I am using this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

This code does work, however I receive a caution:

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIStatusBar' to
>   different enumeration type 'UIBarStyle' (aka) 'enum UIBarStyle').

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Peter

Comment: What is the base iOS SDK version you are using? Please note that the enum "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent" is available for iOS7.0 and upwards only.

Comment: Works like a charm for me.. I assume that you are using iOS7 since you never answered Subzero about it?

Comment: I have answered him.  I am on xcode 5 running on 7.0

Comment: Apparently, the line above is correct and should not throw a warning. However, can you please elaborate as to what you mean when you say "navigation status bar"? Do you mean to say only the status bar or is there a navigation bar/controller as well in your code?

Comment: I mean the status bar (cell signal, time, battery) and the navigation title.

Comment: The code you posted is not the problem. Some where else you must be setting the `barStyle` property (or calling the `setBarStyle:` method) and passing one of the `UIStatusBarStyle...` values by mistake instead of one the `UIBarStyle...` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updating status bar color you can do this

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

and you should have this defined

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

for the navigation bar text color

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
[self.navigationItem.title = @"Test"];
```